# How to compile the kernel with debug symbols?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-building

I've already finishing compiling the kernel from source,

but how to compile it with debug symbols,what additional steps to I need to take?

Answer (score 9):

You need `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` on the config.

More exactly, the question is `Compile the kernel with debug info (DEBUG_INFO) [N/y/?]` and it's under the `Kernel debugging (DEBUG_KERNEL) [Y/n/?]` header. You may need to enable some other option below this one to get to the right one.

Comment: How to debug the kernel with gdb after that?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~kearns/001lab.d/kernel_gdb.html) on google but YMMV.

Comment: I've already compiled the kernel with `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`,but `gdb /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9/vmlinux /proc/kcore` still can't read symbols:`Reading symbols from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9/vmlinux...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/ seems to be a solid guide to attaching the debugger to a kernel.

Comment: Here is a wonderfull guide to debug kernel http://techvolve.blogspot.com/2014/04/debugging-virtualbox-vms-linux-kernel.html .